# App crashes after update. Core data error

Tags: core-data, crash, core-data-migration

I released in app store version of my app 1.1. Then I change my database and released version of app 1.2. After update app crashes when it starts. Can you help me? I have got this error:

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x1e182af0 {URL=file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/CE08D1B7-3457-4654-B1DA-86AAC25CC6D8/Documents/DataModel.sqlite, metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    AppUser = <72f4a69b 62ebdb70 4cc9cc62 a5e256e5 25959da5 6cfad758 9f6b269d 43e1ecf1>;
    Comment = <788972fe 80274647 72ec8208 4140ff92 0ab98923 880e70e8 d9867f51 e7b847e9>;
    Friend = <67c863fe e2f6e86f fc419fd9 13d6a86f 9e53eddf 59be2c66 2c48972c a52aad08>;
    Gallery = <f6760bb4 67312c33 a40c7807 57550cce a2a4d699 9b2aab0b 5758cbb2 febdbb1e>;
    Image = <09c8a368 7da0eda2 f3cbd57b 90fc19e3 572b0456 61f7721b 29b329f3 edd27cd1>;
    Post = <14b4277b c8870cc9 a2b42894 ac549a9f 51fa899d 6270cf9a 542c29f1 433ae232>;
    PostBody = <86d4998a f19d61cc 98804a95 17b0c32a b7d0100a 57f0ee64 307a51cf ca087fd4>;
    Region = <96801c5d bfb5af34 bb83c7d7 c41ef4df 267efc18 6c6f46b1 07715f4d 8dff0ead>;
    SocialNet = <71290cd1 ac2dd061 49fb9766 f0019440 6d59f930 755f8c06 bbc9cc84 baaf04e2>;
    Tag = <a506a246 97683534 dfb6a120 c440ac0e 3075d305 2d22bd69 d27c33c8 0c5db8f5>;
    Theme = <9412b895 04891719 8c9342ba 7616ee61 3df27a2c 57efa3ac a7b97d0c 4d0d8dd6>;
    ThemeAll = <95d80c80 18755ade 6ca83731 222a95c6 2575c83c 3e266ef3 667ef48c 850ed742>;
    ThemeDisplayable = <ece3436f d55e61a0 a3b2c0b1 0179a52e 16842058 28614280 37c9092f e5cab28f>;
    User = <49e38bf1 225eed1f f5cd771a 6e7707b4 1a2f0629 79aad8bc d220eaf6 5395a97f>;
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "218F9A44-2939-49AB-A9F3-3A90E2205F26";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store}, {
URL = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/CE08D1B7-3457-4654-B1DA-86AAC25CC6D8/Documents/DataModel.sqlite";
metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        AppUser = <72f4a69b 62ebdb70 4cc9cc62 a5e256e5 25959da5 6cfad758 9f6b269d 43e1ecf1>;
        Comment = <788972fe 80274647 72ec8208 4140ff92 0ab98923 880e70e8 d9867f51 e7b847e9>;
        Friend = <67c863fe e2f6e86f fc419fd9 13d6a86f 9e53eddf 59be2c66 2c48972c a52aad08>;
        Gallery = <f6760bb4 67312c33 a40c7807 57550cce a2a4d699 9b2aab0b 5758cbb2 febdbb1e>;
        Image = <09c8a368 7da0eda2 f3cbd57b 90fc19e3 572b0456 61f7721b 29b329f3 edd27cd1>;
        Post = <14b4277b c8870cc9 a2b42894 ac549a9f 51fa899d 6270cf9a 542c29f1 433ae232>;
        PostBody = <86d4998a f19d61cc 98804a95 17b0c32a b7d0100a 57f0ee64 307a51cf ca087fd4>;
        Region = <96801c5d bfb5af34 bb83c7d7 c41ef4df 267efc18 6c6f46b1 07715f4d 8dff0ead>;
        SocialNet = <71290cd1 ac2dd061 49fb9766 f0019440 6d59f930 755f8c06 bbc9cc84 baaf04e2>;
        Tag = <a506a246 97683534 dfb6a120 c440ac0e 3075d305 2d22bd69 d27c33c8 0c5db8f5>;
        Theme = <9412b895 04891719 8c9342ba 7616ee61 3df27a2c 57efa3ac a7b97d0c 4d0d8dd6>;
        ThemeAll = <95d80c80 18755ade 6ca83731 222a95c6 2575c83c 3e266ef3 667ef48c 850ed742>;
        ThemeDisplayable = <ece3436f d55e61a0 a3b2c0b1 0179a52e 16842058 28614280 37c9092f e5cab28f>;
        User = <49e38bf1 225eed1f f5cd771a 6e7707b4 1a2f0629 79aad8bc d220eaf6 5395a97f>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "218F9A44-2939-49AB-A9F3-3A90E2205F26";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
};
reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}
```

Comment: Are you versioning your coredata Model ?

Comment: The above error indicates that the app which is currently installed on the simulator/device, its coredata is not found in the model versions. I mean old version of Coredata model is not found.

Comment: Btw, you wrote the migration code in the persistentCoordinator method present in your AppDelegate file ?

Comment: @RajanBalana yes. I made a bad mistake. When I released version 1.2 with new DB I accidentally changed my old DB. I think this is a primary problem crashing app. What do I need fixing?

Comment: After versioning have you made the new .xcdatamodel as active?

Comment: Do you have backup of your app's code? I mean backup of old coredatamodel? If you don't have , I don't know what to do in the case.

Comment: @RajanBalana yes I have. I take my old DB from version 1.1 and make a new DB based on old DB (v 1.1)

Comment: Are you sure that the new the your app is using the new .xcdatamodel not the previous one. But the error is showing related to modification in database.

Comment: @Sveta but as u said, u changed the old DB, then that actually mean you don't have old DB now !

Comment: @RajanBalana I make git reset and take old DB and put in my new version 1.3 and make new DB based on this DB

Comment: Okay, so you have the version 1.1 DB now. You tried running your app now ? Is it Still not working ?

Comment: @RajanBalana I have 3 versions of my app (v.1.1, v.1.2 this version in app store and v.1.3). I tried install cases throw iTunes 1.1-1.2-1.3, 1.1-1.3, 1.2-1.3. All cases work. But when I take iphone with v.1.2 from app store and install new v.1.3 throw xcode app crashes.

Comment: There could be a case that version 1.2 is not the correct version which Xcode is looking for, you might have changed something in version 1.2. or it can be the changes which are made in version 1.3 are not eligible for lightweight coredata migration process. Can you confirm that? Are your coredata changes in v 1.3 is eligible for lightweight migration ?

Comment: @RajanBalana yes, coredata changes in v.1.3 is eligible. I add 1 entity, removed 1 entity and changed some attributes.

Comment: @Sveta can't comment further, I don't know what else could be the problem, lets wait for experts comments

Comment: @RajanBalana when I showing all .mom my DataModel2.mom is null. I have just DataModel.mom and DataModel3.mom

Comment: @Sveta OOPS! That could be a problem, But I don't know how to resolve it, why don't you start over creating your core data model again, version by version.

Comment: @RajanBalana I make it. I take my old model from v.1.1 and copy to new v.1.3 and created new model based on old model (from v.1.1)

Comment: @Sveta Great :) Cheers !

Comment: @RajanBalana )) but it doesn't work when I install v.1.3 on v.1.2 from app store (through xcode). But when I install v.1.2 on device through iTunes and then I install v.1.3 it works. Paradox

Comment: @Sveta Try clearing the derived data from the Xcode project and try cleaning the project. As you might have made lots of things with coredata models.

Comment: @RajanBalana I've made it, but it doesn't help...

Comment: @Sveta Sorry cannot say anything more than that :(

Comment: @RajanBalana Consider moving conversation to chat